# Missing tag in Beautiful Soup object

Tags: parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i have some page, opening it with urllib2 and then passing through BeautifulSoup (without any bs4 parameters)

when I`m watching page source in browser there is my target tag 
but in bs4 object there is no such tag

can I somehow workaround this ?

Answer (score 0):

The tag you want is probably loaded dynamically using javascript. There are two ways to scrape those:

- Use a headless browser like selenium, phantomjs etc.
- Inspect the traffic generated by the website and locate the AJAX call (for example using chrome developer tools). Use the AJAX call in your script instead of the URL you are trying to scrape.

Comment: how to make ajax call?

Comment: It is just a normal HTTP request, you have to inspect the call in your browser.